# PySide2 - Program crashes when calling QFileSystemModel.index()

Tags: python, indexing, pyside2, qfilesystemmodel

I am trying to convert  into Python the following C++ example from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-model-indexes :

C++:

```
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
QModelIndex parentIndex = model->index(QDir::currentPath());
int numRows = model->rowCount(parentIndex);
```

Python:

```
import os
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
model = QFileSystemModel()
parent_index = model.index(os.getcwd())
nb_row = model.rowCount(parent_index)
print(nb_row)
```

but my progam crashes with exit code :

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the code in a CMD/console you will get the following error message:

```
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Which indicates that [`QFileSystemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) uses a QThread (that is also indicated in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#caching-and-performance)), and for a QThread to run it needs an event loop, in this case you must create an instance of [`QApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html):

```py
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileSystemModel

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = QFileSystemModel()
    parent_index = model.index(os.getcwd())
    nb_row = model.rowCount(parent_index)
    print(nb_row)
```

The above is also explicitly indicated in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#details):

> ### Detailed Description
>
> This class provides access to the local filesystem, providing
>   functions for renaming and removing files and directories, and for
>   creating new directories. In the simplest case, it can be used with a
>   suitable display widget as part of a browser or filter.
>
> QFileSystemModel can be accessed using the standard interface provided
>   by QAbstractItemModel, but it also provides some convenience functions
>   that are specific to a directory model. The fileInfo(), isDir(),
>   fileName() and filePath() functions provide information about the
>   underlying files and directories related to items in the model.
>   Directories can be created and removed using mkdir(), rmdir().
>
> **Note: QFileSystemModel requires an instance of QApplication.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

In the case of C++, QApplication was probably created in the main.cpp.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the core dumped problem. But rowCount() return 0 . I open a new question for this new problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59098251

Comment: @u2gilles Your question has already been asked before (I have marked it as a duplicate), the solution is to use directoryLoaded that will notify when the model finishes loading and then you can just verify the rowCount. See https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/9630fef358464a676a6881ad6b73c6e7

Comment: @u2gilles On the other hand in the question of this post you do not point out about rowCount() but it is focused only on the chash so my answer is only limited to it.

Comment: That's why I wrote "a new question for this new problem". Thanks, everything works now. I suppose the directoryLoaded Signal is not necessary in C++ as they don't mention it  "Model/View Programming".

Comment: Wow. Your example in github is great. More concise than the one with the pushButton. You may post it below to enrich this post if you like. Thanks again.

Comment: @u2gilles The example is correct (in C++ you will get "0"), with your code you got "0" because the model is still empty, do not confuse the folders in your directory with the model since they are 2 different things, at the time you wanted get the rowCount the model was not loaded so obviously the number of rows must be "0", but after setting a root starts to load the model, and then I use the directoryLoaded signal to get the row number after load.